# Does Find My iPhone send a notification when being reset?

Tags: notifications, find-my-iphone

If I use Find My iPhone to reset my phone, will it give a notification that it's being reset? Someone has my phone and they will eventually get my passcode and I NEED to reset it so they dont see everything thats on my phone but I don't want them to know that I reset it.

Comment: Just curious... How are they going to get your passcode?

Comment: they're my parents and they are eventually gonna ask for the passcode & i'm going to have to give it to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a remote erase, it's as if the device is new out of the box. The welcome screen is presented to the user.

If the device is activation locked, it will still be locked. If it's not locked, the person in possession of the device can set it up as they choose.

No record of the event is stored - so they may be able to assume you wiped it. If there was a passcode lock and they were guessing, it's not possible for them to know if they caused the erase or you did in all likelihood. If they didn't touch it, they could conclude it was buggy (unlikely) or wiped (likely).

Comment: What do you mean activation locked? And how do you know if its activation locked or not? Thank you!

Comment: Use the search up top and right or [tag:activation-lock]